# How to identify wrong cast in a huge C++ unmanaged application?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

The Application has thousand of classes.
I thought to convert all c-style cast to dynamic cast by regular expression but I failed because it is very difficult identify the Casts's argument expression.

I am using VS2010 (but a have a ready previous version on VS 2008 too)

Do you know a Tool exists that perform the cast check ?

Thanks for any hint

Comment: What regular expression did you try?  How did it fail?

Comment: Tools like purify/valgrind may also help.  They identify bad memory access, sadly when they are done so some times after the bad cast has been done.  B

Comment: @Tony: the regex he used is *almost* irrelevant -- I'm reasonably certain there's no such thing as a regex that can identify C-style casts accurately. Something like `(T)` *could* be, but isn't necessarily, a cast. You have to parse the preceding code to know whether `T` it's in a place that a cast is possible and whether `T` identifies a type.

Comment: @Jerry: I agree it's ugly, but perfection for the general case isn't required, he's doing a one-off conversion and only needs it to work for the code in question.  Depending on how large the code base and varied the coding style is, a regexp may or may not be able to work, but I'm curious about his effort and experience....

Comment: @Tony: Even for a one-off conversion, it's not usable for anything but the *most* trivial code. Just for example, consider things like `int x(int);`. Just for this common, trivial case, the RE gets pretty complex (needs to check that the cast-like `(int)` is followed by something identifier-like). Unless his "thousands of classes" follow very specific styles *religiously*, it's going to take a lot of luck to get a result that compiles at all.

Comment: @Jerry: I think you overestimate the hassles.  Even with the simple `'([A-Za-z_][^)]*\*)'` on 140k of implementation files I found 231 positives of which only 4 were false (function parameters).  (Remember he's interested in `dynamic_cast<>` candidates, hence the '\*').  Function parameters can be eliminated by observing that they're preceeded by an arbitrary identifier, whereas the only identifier casts was preceeded by in the 227 matches was `return`... anything else possible?  Getting pretty close with minimal effort ;-).

Answer (score 4):

g++ has an option that, when enabled, prints out warnings for c-style casts.

> -Wold-style-cast (C++ and Objective-C++ only)
>
> Warn if an old-style (C-style) cast to a non-void type is
>   used within a C++ program.  The
>   new-style casts (dynamic_cast,
>   static_cast, reinterpret_cast, and
>   const_cast) are less vulnerable to
>   unintended effects and much easier to
>   search for.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [PC-lint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/pcl.htm) - it produces messages for this and a *lot* more.